# Getting an instance error on my Laravel listener

Tags: php, sql, laravel, listener

This is the error =>

> "message": "Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Listeners\SlackUserDropListener::handle() must be an instance of
>   App\Listeners\App\Events\UserDropEvent, instance of
>   App\Events\UserDropEvent given"

My code is below:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UsersPermission;
use App\Models\UsersDrop;
use App\Models\Trace;

class SlackUserDropListener {

     /**
      * Create the event listener.
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function __construct()
     {
         //
     }
     /**
      * Handle the event.
      *
      * @param  \App\Events\UserDropEvent  $event
      * @return void
      */
     public function handle(App\Events\UserDropEvent $event) {

        $user = $event->user;
          $text  = ">*Qualified lead has been dropped by agent*\n";
          $text .= ">Client Name: ".$user->first_name." ".$user->last_name."\n";
          $text .= ">Assigned Agent: ".$event->agent_name."\n";
          $text .= ">Drop Reason: ".$event->drop_reason."\n";
          $text .= ">Client BO Profile: https://***.com/users/edit/".$user->id."\n";
            try{
                $client = new Client;
                $slack_channel = config('slack.webhookConsultants');
                if(\App::environment() != "production") $slack_channel = 
                                                config('slack.webhookTest');
                $client->request('POST', $slack_channel, ['json' => [
                    "text" => $text,
                ]]);
            }catch(\Exception $e) {}

            return "SlackUserDrop OK";
     }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a \ before App in your handle declaration.

Comment: @aynber Spot on my friend. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So, because of this line:

```
namespace App\Listeners;
```

all calls within this file are assumed to be within that namespace.

Thus, this bit:

```
App\Events\UserDropEvent $event
```

gets interpreted as:

```
App\Listeners\App\Events\UserDropEvent $event
```

You can preface things with a `\`, to tell PHP to start at the namespace root:

```
\App\Events\UserDropEvent $event
```

or, you can put this at the top of your file (with the other `use` declarations):

```
use App\Events\UserDropEvent;
```

and do this in your function:

```
UserDropEvent $event
```